# Transfer Domain to Azure

Tags: azure

Our company wants to transfer the domains from an Hostmysite provider to Azure without downtime.

Could you recommend to me the best way to do it?

Comment: impossible to say without knowing details. Traffic Manager would, probably, work

Comment: "Could you recommend to me the best way to do it?" Ask your new DNS provider/registrar it should be able to help you because otherwise your question is completely offtopic here as not being related to programming.

Comment: We have Traffic Manager already in azure. I would research about it

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, I think you misunderstood my question, this is not related to programing, this is related to infrastructure or azure configuration. That's why I set the tag [Azure].Thanks!

Comment: "this is not related to programing" And that is exactly the problem because this site is ONLY for questions related to programming. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic where you can see that "infrastructure" appears at point 7 of the list of OFFTOPIC subjects here.

Answer (score 1):

Best effort answer, but I will avoid the part "without downtime" because that is subjective what acceptable downtime is, how much must be "moved", how tidy you are, etc.

A short recipe would be something like:

1. On azure, in your Azure subscription, create an "DNS zone" resource.
2. Rebuild the content, manually or by scripting.
3. You can test the dns by shell or even redirecting your workstation to use this dns. You find the ns addresses in your Azure DNS resource.
4. When ready, delegate your domain to the new DNS.

[Delegation of DNS zones with Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-domain-delegation), "nearby" articles can also be useful.

Everything, up to 4) is harmless and has almost no cost. So you can do several attempts and use your time. The last task 4), your current DNS provider can help you with.

Let me talk a little about downtime. Example of a bad scenario, you forgot something important like MX records. Can't help you there, you are on your own. But let us say that everything is set up correctly, then it will be almost no downtime. It will take some time before every dns in the world has discovered the change, but it doesn't matter much because the old dns and the new dns, says exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you short recipe, I would research out more about it